# dynamic file picker.io control doesn't work

Tags: filepicker.io

I Have Created Dynamic FilePicker Control on Button Click Event of Jquery
but the button click event of this dynamic control does not open the filepicker.io popup where files get uploaded on filepicker...

Below is the html code by which i have created this control in jquery

```html
<input type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="Acdgfv0GWQXyMKwqVMfMHz" data-fp-mimetypes="image/*" data-fp-container="modal" data-fp-services="COMPUTER" class="uploadImg btn border-blue-btn" tabindex="31" style="display:none">                                <button type="button" class="uploadImg btn border-blue-btn">Pick File</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filepicker javascript library construct widgets immediately after script is loaded. Using filepicker with any client side rendering library requires manually call

```
filepicker.constructWidget();
```

method on Dom element. You need to set element type as 'filepicker' etc.

Basic example:

```
var input = $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'filepicker',
    class:'picker',
}).appendTo(config.results);

filepicker.constructWidget(input);
```

And full working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/krystiangw/hfg6k8u2/

Answer (score 0):

Did you include filepicker.js library?

Please try this example (link: https://jsfiddle.net/gy2gLvkw/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//api.filepicker.io/v2/filepicker.js"></script>
<input type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="Acdgfv0GWQXyMKwqVMfMHz" data-fp-mimetypes="image/*" data-fp-container="modal" data-fp-services="COMPUTER" class="uploadImg btn border-blue-btn" tabindex="31" style="display:none" onchange="alert(event.fpfile.url)">
```

I've added `onchange="alert(event.fpfile.url)"` to input element so that the url is displayed after upload.

Comment: yes i have used the js library...in same page i had 2 filepicker controls...one of is defined in html code ( which is working well ) while 2nd one is created dynamic on button click (jquery) event...